# How do I assign a number cell to a text cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros, vlookup

I have imported data from the web on the Peruvian Football League which will refresh and update. I have taken an average % of 2 samples of data for each team. I also have a fixture list and want to assign  the average % to the specific team in the fixture list it represents. I have considered a macro but I am unsure if this would work. If im going about this all wrong please let me know.

[image: Data]

[image: Fixture List]

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking: which number cell do you want to assign to which text cell?

Comment: I would like numbers in Column O to pull through to the respective team on fixtures sheet into Column B and F

Comment: Look into VLOOKUP() formula. It should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Could you please upload the Macro you are using with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula should work in `Sheet2.B2:B9` and `Sheet2.E2:E9`:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1.$O$"&MATCH(A2,Sheet1.$A$3:$A$18,0)+2)
```

First set the formula into `Sheet2.B2`, then copy into the other cells. Because `A2` is a relative reference, it will adjust automatically to the equivalent offsets in the other cells.

`MATCH()` finds the position of the current team in the list of team names, then 2 is added to give the row number, and `=INDIRECT()` is used to insert the value of the corresponding `O` column.

Comment: If it solves your problem, perhaps you would mark it as solved, so that others can see that there is a solution.